# On the rank of product of matrices of order 10

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I had been asked the following question:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two $10 \times 10$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ with $rank(AB)=6$. What is the maximum possible value of rank of $BA$?

First, I realized that both $rank(A)$ and $rank(B)$ are at least 6. Further, from Sylvester's inequality, we must have
$$rank(A)+rank(B) \leq 16.$$
Now, counting down all the possibilities (For instance, one possibility is $rank(A)=6$ and $rank(B)=10$), I arrived at a possible maximum value of $rank(BA)$ which is 8. For this to happen we must have $rank(A) = rank(B) = 8$.

I tried, but could not get an answer to the question, `do there exist two matrices $A$ and $B$ each with rank $8$ and that $rank(AB)=6$, $rank(BA)=8$?

Comment: I'll give you a hint on the construction: decompose $\mathbb{C}^{10}$ into three parts and choose nice simple matrices $A,B$.  Or equivalently: remember the 2x2 example $A,B$ where $AB=0$ but $BA\neq 0$ and adapt that to this example.

Comment: Let $A=\operatorname{diag}(0,0,1,\ldots,1)$. It suffices to find a matrix $B$ whose last eight columns are linearly independent and whose last eight rows have rank $6$. This should be pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: That was pretty easy to guess. I hadn't thought wisely and had not given much thought. Thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Sylvester's inequality
$$\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq 6+10= 16.$$
Because
$$\operatorname{rank}(BA)\leq\min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}$$
For $\operatorname{rank}(BA)$ to be as large as possible, the ranks of $A$ and $B$ must be as close as possible while satisfying Sylvester's inequality, thus $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)=8$.

Following @user10354138's comment, we will utilize the matrices
\begin{align*}
X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} && Y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \end{align*}
with $$XY=0\qquad YX = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Let
$$A=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,X,X),B=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,Y,Y)$$
We have $$\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)=8$$
and$$AB=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),BA=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,Y,Y)$$
Therefore,
$$\operatorname{rank}(AB)=6,\operatorname{rank}(BA)=8$$